# Ios use Pasteboard get error "Operation not authorized"

Tags: ios, pasteboard

When i use `UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];` get some data from Pasteboard, then got this error, How to resolve this. Im using Xcode13.4 and ios15.4 phone.

> 2023-03-15 17:43:46.557427+0800[89748:38866953] [Pasteboard]
> ...requesting item failed with error: Error Domain=PBErrorDomain
> Code=13 "Operation not authorized."
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Operation not authorized.}